# How get .net framework versions on client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want get all .net framework versions on a client machine using asp.net application.

I am using `Request.Browser.GetClrVersions()` but it returns `0.0`.

`Request.Browser.ClrVersion` also returns `0.0` although I have 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 frameworks installed on my machine.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the .Net version installed on the client, or server?

Comment: I am trying to get versions on client machine.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sr28: That is unrelated since it doesn't apply to ASP.NET.

Comment: What browser do you use? Not sure if all browsers send it along the user agent.

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching the *actual* problem from the wrong direction. What will you use this information (if it's even possible to obtain it) to *do*?

Comment: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/blog/archive/20070919/ for client .net version

Comment: @patrick-hofman : I am using IE 11

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem on recent browsers (IE and Chrome).

It seems the user agent doesn't supply the .NET version any more.

These are my test results:

```
var x = Request.Browser.GetClrVersions();
// returns an array containing 0.0

var y = Request.Browser.ClrVersion;
// returns an string containing 0.0

var z = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
// returns 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' on IE11
// return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2120.0 Safari/537.36' on Chrome Canary
```

So no sign of the .NET versions installed.

Comment: @Vinod: was this useful to you?

Comment: Thanq for the reply, but it is not useful for me...your code did not retrieve framework versions.

Comment: @Vinodkumar: True, and I explained it isn't possible that way now since the browsers don't supply it.

Comment: But how can I solve this. I have requirement. Is there any other way ?